# input/output error when running the chown on mount s3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, s3fs

Hi All I have mounted a bucket to ubuntu 20.04 and I mount the my s3 bucket using the below command

```
s3fs BucketName pathtobucketfolder -o passwd_file=$HOME/.passwd-s3fs,nonempty,rw,allow_other,mp_umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000 -o url=http://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,endpoint=us-east-1,use_path_request_style
```

Now I am trying to change the permission on that folder but getting input error

> chown: changing ownership of '/home/test-user/bucket/': Input/output error,.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

This was tracked in https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/2138 and fixed via https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/pull/2147 and version 1.92 includes this.